# Unable to generate cert using openssl via Jenkins job

Tags: shell, jenkins, openssl, ssl-certificate

I need to generate root ca certificate of some env and add it to mmc on windows machine.
All this needs to be done through a Jenkins job running on a Linux node.

Here is what i am trying to do:

```
openssl s_client -connect $URL:$PORT -showcerts < /dev/null > a.cer
awk '/-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----/,/-----END CERTIFICATE-----/' a.cer | tail -22 > env.cer
echo "================================================"
cat env.cer
```

Output :

```
Loading 'screen' into random state - done
2728:error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version:.\ssl\s23_clnt.c:455:
+ awk /-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----/,/-----END CERTIFICATE-----/ a.cer 
+ tail -22 
+ echo ================================================ 
================================================
+ cat env.cer
```

I am able to generate env.cer manually using above commands on another linux box.
Kindly suggest. Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try with latest, updated version of `openssl`.

Comment: this openssl command is working with OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013 locally
but not working with OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017 .